# É inviavel usar Domain-Driven Design trabalhando sozinho?

Tags: arquitetura-de-software, ddd

Tenho estudado muito sobre DDD e estou com essa dúvida que vem me incomodando desde que eu comecei ler sobre "strategic design". Eu trabalho com programação desde 2009 e a maior parte do tempo sempre trabalhei sozinho. Já desenvolvi softwares com escopo fechado, um cliente especifico e tudo mais. Mas no momento estou trabalhando em alguns projetos "software as a service" desenvolvidos pra ser vendido depois, ou seja, sem nenhum cliente específico esperando o software pra empresa dele.

Logicamente, pra conseguir modelar as coisas corretamente eu tenho disponível especialistas de domínio que fornecem os requisitos e tudo mais. O fato é que não tenho uma equipe. Acontece que li que se eu trabalho sozinho eu tenho que esquecer DDD e arranjar outro jeito de trabalhar e isso me preocupou um pouco, porque vários problemas eu já vi que sem usar o DDD ficam extremamente mais complicados.

Quando comecei a ler sobre "strategic design", sobre subdomains e bounded contexts isso me pareceu muito util. Na realidade, vários problemas que tive em desenvolvimentos anteriores pareceram ser muito mais simples usando essas ideias. O problema é o fato de que ao ler sobre isso vejo muito foco em equipes: "alocar uma equipe para cada contexto delimitado".

Isso é claramente impossível trabalhando sozinho, mas ainda assim não me parece que eu não possa aplicar as ideias do "strategic design".

Dessa forma o que eu quero saber é o seguinte: levando em conta tudo isso e principalmente que estou trabalhando em projetos que não tem prazo e nem escopo fechado, é possível eu tirar proveito das ideias do DDD, principalmente do "strategic design"? Se sim, de que forma posso fazer isso?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Acredito que essa pergunta não tenha uma resposta objetiva mas vou dar minha opinião de todo jeito.

Mais do que o tamanho da equipe, a escolha da arquitetura da aplicação está mais relacionada ao tamanho e complexidade do problema/domínio/modelo sendo implementado e o tempo estimado de vida da aplicação.

É necessário colocar na balança o esforço em se executar DDD versus a frequência e complexidade da manutenção da aplicação. Nem sempre o esforço será recompensado.

Por outro lado, eu não gostaria de desencorajar ninguém a tentar DDD quando for possível. Querendo ou não, um fator muito decisivo sempre será o desejo do desenvolvedor em aprender algo novo que promete facilitar sua vida a longo prazo.

Comment: +1 porque responde bem a pergunta. Mas existe sim uma resposta objetiva já que o DDD possui uma proposta objetiva e podemos enquadrar projetos nesta proposta ou fora dela. Uma grande parte do DDD é justamente para resolver problemas de projetos complexos, mas outra parte é para resolver **regras** complexas, as quais eventualmente podem ser resolvidas por uma única pessoa. Então, exatamente como você respondeu, o que determina as esolhas é o problema e não apenas a quantidade de gente envolvida.

Comment: Eu classifiquei como "não objetiva" porque considero complexidade um conceito subjetivo, difícil de medir. Alguém precisa julgar essa complexidade para avaliar se o uso de DDD é apropriado.

Answer (score 1):

Eu recomendaria o uso de DDD mesmo vc programando sozinho, a menos que o projeto seja pequeno, e não tenha regras de negócio complexas.
O DDD te obriga a entender mais do domínio, e esse entendimento é essencial para a produção de um bom software.

Answer (score 1):

## DDD não está diretamente ligado ao tamanho da equipe

DDD é uma estratégia para lidar com domínios em que há uma riqueza de conceitos e de interações entre eles. Quando se está interessado em modelar esta complexidade, convém considerar DDD. Naturalmente, em cenários assim talvez seja mais natural termos várias pessoas envolvidas, mas não existe restrição neste sentido.

Acredito que já adquiriu o "sentimento" necessário para identificar os cenários de aplicação de DDD, conforme o terceiro parágrafo da sua pergunta. Este mesmo parágrafo fornece uma orientação cristalina para o uso ou não de DDD: assim como qualquer outra estratégia, é preciso observar o contexto. DDD não é aplicável em todos os casos, assim como qualquer outra estratégia. Precisamos desenvolver o discernimento acerca do cenário adequado para o seu emprego.

Adicionalmente, conforme a pergunta sugere, uma mesma aplicação pode ter partes desenvolvidas com o apoio de DDD e outras não. E, novamente, não há nenhum problema com isso. Provavelmente não irá empregar DDD em um problema que pode ser resolvido com uma planilha de cálculo em poucas horas, ou um script para imprimir arquivos depositados em um diretório. Por outro lado, provavelmente fará uso se há interesse em modelar e registrar conceitos como eventos relevantes a um dado domínio, assim como operações, regras de negócio em abundância e outros. Definitivamente não é uma explanação tão clara quanto gostaríamos, mas acredito que fornece alguma orientação.

Por fim, quantas estratégias estão vivas após duas décadas?